# Modify Wordpress Comment From For AMP Html

Tags: comments, comments-template

Im using a custom filter to change the fields, but can´t figure out how to change the order of the fields in the comment form.

Could you please how to modify this WordPress comment From

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( $args['action'] ); ?>" method="post" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id_form'] ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['class_form'] ); ?>"<?php echo $html5 ? ' novalidate' : ''; ?>>
```

for amp wordpress theme with function

to be like this

```
<form action-xhr="<?php echo esc_url( $args['action'] ); ?>" method="post" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id_form'] ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['class_form'] ); ?>"<?php echo $html5 ? ' novalidate' : ''; ?> target="_top">
```

Comment: Would you please update your question so that it contains the filter used to change the fields?